# C# Cosmos User Kit Doesn't appear on Visual Studio Templates

Tags: c#, vb.net

I installed Cosmos User Kit on Visual Studio 2013 Templates and why it doesn't show on my templates? I tried to reinstall it and restart my laptop and it didn't worked.